# How to use registerNetworkCallback with PendingIntent?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) was deprecated in API level 28 and Google advices to use registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent).

I tried registerNetworkCallback with [ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) and it works, but I want to use PendingIntent.

What confuse me is the description of [public void registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest request, PendingIntent operation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> The operation is an Intent broadcast that goes to a broadcast receiver
>   that you registered with Context#registerReceiver or through the
>    tag in an AndroidManifest.xml file

`Context#registerReceiver` accepts `IntentFilter` as an argument, while `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` requires `Intent`.

Here is my code, and NetworkStateReceiver::onReceive is not called.

```
private fun getNetworkIntent(): PendingIntent {
    if (networkPendingIntent != null) {
        return networkPendingIntent!!
    }

    val intent = Intent(this, NetworkStateReceiver::class.java)
    networkPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    return networkPendingIntent!!
}

private fun getNetworkRequest(): NetworkRequest {
    return NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .build()
}

private fun registerNetworkUpdates() {
    var cm =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
    cm?.registerNetworkCallback(getNetworkRequest(), getNetworkIntent())
}
```

Why?
Should I also call `Context#registerReceiver`? But what action should I use with `IntentFilter` if `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` was deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I made it works. First I need to add the receiver to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver 
        android:name=".NetworkStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Second, `NetworkStateReceiver#onReceive` is called only once when the connection was offline and becomes available. So every-time I need to send anything when the connection is offline I have to call `registerNetworkUpdates`.

Third, I have to call `unregisterNetworkCallback` before calling `registerNetworkCallback`. If I called `registerNetworkCallback` twice with the same `Intent`, `NetworkStateReceiver#onReceive` was called twice. And I used `applicationContext` instead of `this` when creating `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`.

Comment: Once I register such callback with a PendingIntent, the receiver instantly gets it even if the network doesn't change. How do you make if work only when the network changes?